# Is there any way to disable all the errors and warnings that appear in the console?

Tags: reactjs

I don't want to show the warnings in the console for a certain development environment. Is there any way to achieve that? My application was bootstrapped using create react app.

Comment: You don't disable them, you *fix them*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using React, my guess is you are already using babel. There's a plugin for that purpose. It's called [babel-plugin-transform-remove-console](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console/). This will exclude all `console.log`'s statement during the build process.
Install that in your app and configure it via `.babelrc` as follows:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
}
```

You can also specify the variant(s) of the console functions to exclude:

```
{
  "plugins": [ ["transform-remove-console", { "exclude": [ "error", "warn"] }] ]
}
```

My advise is to not use console logs in your code except necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The logs are generated by proptypes and i actually dont have time currently to fix them all so i wanted to disable them for my production build currently.

Comment: Is there any way for me to remove console without having to build it? I need to remove them based on devlopment environments

Comment: You can convert your `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js` and then set the plugin based on `NODE_ENV`

Answer (score 1):

In my App.js I have the following code for accomplishing this:

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

componentDidMount() {
    // The following lines are a workaround
    // in order to stop getting warnings about timer
    // See: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/97#issuecomment-365456531
    YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Setting a timer']);
    const _console = _.clone(console);
    console.warn = message => {
      if (message.indexOf('Setting a timer') <= -1) {
        _console.warn(message);
      }
    };
}
```

Comment: I actually needed a solution for react not react-native.

Comment: I see... No charge, then ;)